# How to change RGB to CMYK color specific in Adobe Illustrator ?

Tags: adobe, photoshop, adobe-illustrator

I am using adobe illustrator cc 2018. I have a color #ff32cb. I want to convert it to CMYK same as it is looking. If i use this code in cmyk then its not same.(see image attached. Right color is rgb, i want same in left in cmyk) Please help me how to do it. Thanks

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DL7bi.png)

Comment: stackoverflow is for programming questions, for general graphic design please use https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com

Comment: Sorry, next time i will keep in mind

Answer (score 0):

[image: .]

You can find the window color and switch into CMYK from top right options

Answer (score -1):

You can change RGB color code to CMYK code here is an steps:

[image]

Comment: I did this already, you can check difference in screenshot, i already attached in question